# JavaFX table- how to add components and relate them to other scene?

Tags: javafx, tableview

Is there any way --by clicking on the embedded button -- to open a new scene that is related to the tableview raw selected : 
for example :

```
public class TestClass extends Application {
    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("A", "B", "email@example.com","info"),
            new Person("X", "Y", "email2@example.com","info"),
            new Person("Z", "W", "email2@example.com","info")

        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        final Label actionTaken = new Label();

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

        TableColumn<Person, Person> btnCol = new TableColumn<>("info");
        btnCol.setMinWidth(150);
        btnCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Person, Person>, ObservableValue<Person>>() {
          @Override public ObservableValue<Person> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, Person> features) {
              return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(features.getValue());
          }
        });
        btnCol.setComparator(new Comparator<Person>() {
          public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
            return p1.getLikes().compareTo(p2.getLikes());
          }
        });
        btnCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Person>, TableCell<Person, Person>>() {
          @Override public TableCell<Person, Person> call(TableColumn<Person, Person> btnCol) {
              Stage stage = null;
              return new AddCell(stage, table);
          }
        });

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol, btnCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, actionTaken);
        VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
        stage.show();


     }
}
```

the Person Class :

```
    public class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;
        private final SimpleStringProperty infos;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email, String infos) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
            this.infos = new SimpleStringProperty(infos);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLikes() {
            return infos.get();
        }

        public void setLikes(String likes) {
            this.infos.set(likes);
        }
    }

}
```

the AddCell class :

```
public class AddCell extends TableCell<Person, Boolean> {

    final Button addButton       = new Button("Elément");
    final StackPane paddedButton = new StackPane();
    final DoubleProperty buttonY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private MessageCmiService messageService=new MessageCmiServiceImpl(); 

    public AddCell(final Stage stage, final TableView table) {
      paddedButton.setPadding(new Insets(3));
      paddedButton.getChildren().add(addButton);
      addButton.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
              buttonY.set(mouseEvent.getScreenY());
            }
          });
      addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    //??? 
    // get the info

     }
            });

    }
    @Override 
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
        else{
          setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
          setGraphic(paddedButton);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your handler, you can do

```
Person currentPerson = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
```

which gives you access to all the data in the current row.